# How to get city and province based on current user's location

Tags: javascript, php, google-api

I am working on a project where I need to provide a search interface for user where they will be able to search location on their country. I have use google location for this using autocomplete and get all locations from api.
Is it possible to get location based on current country?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get user's current location by using geoplugin third party site using PHP:

```
$userIp = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
$geoPlugin = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=$userIp"));
$user_country = $geoPlugin["geoplugin_countryName"];
$user_city = $geoPlugin["geoplugin_city"];
```